# Stack Overflow podcasts on Spotify

Tags: support, podcast

This may not be the right place to ask, but is there any way we could get the Stack Overflow podcast on Spotify? I would love to start listening on a regular basis, but the only time I really have is on the go.

If the podcasts were on Spotify, I could download them when they come out and listen to them whenever. Because Spotify is a paid service (or on the free service you are forced to listen to ads) I can only assume Stack Overflow would get a kickback for the amount of listens they get. Seems like a win win to me.

Comment: I thought the SE podcasts are on SoundCloud, why doesn't that work for you? I don't understand why they have to be on Spotify?

Comment: I didn't realise they were on soundcloud.

Comment: They are: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange

Comment: awesome! should I delete the question? with this (new to me) information its kind of a silly question

Comment: @SaggingRufus Still a perfectly valid question, I'd leave it.

Comment: _"I can only assume Stack Overflow would get a kickback for the amount of listens they get"_  I would have to assume the opposite.  I mean, Stack Overflow isn't paying you a kickback for the answers you write, is it?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom considering everyone else on Spotify gets money per listen, I don't see why Stack Overflow would be any different

Comment: I feel like saying SoundCloud or nothing is like the famous "Model-T can be in any color so long as its black" from Henry Ford... we saw how that worked out...

Comment: @joshmcode Ford became a massive success?

Comment: @NathanArthur sure, but not with a bunch of cars that were all the same color. I'm just saying the argument that people should just be happy with SoundCloud isn't a sound one.

Comment: These arguments _against_ spotify are not very good. The cost in time and money is trivial and the convenience to listeners is massive (more people use spotifiy than soundcloud). IMO going to spotify is a no-brainer. The fact that it's not on itunes is a crime of another sort...

Comment: @JustusEapen Agreed. Convenience, and discoverability, I might add.

Comment: @JustusEapen Do you know the actual cost in time and money? Or the convenience to listeners, and how many it would affect? What makes you think the podcast isn't on iTunes?

Comment: I was wrong about it not being on itunes. I looked under bad search terms ("stackoverflow" not "stack overflow").  You can see that Stack Overflow is a good fit here: https://blog.libsyn.com/2016/01/12/how-to-get-your-podcast-into-spotify/

Comment: Any decent podcast app will let you download them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We use [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange) for now because it wraps up nicely in our (kinda laborious) production process for these, but I don't think we'd be opposed to syndicating elsewhere if enough folks expressed some interest, especially from folks that don't currently manage to remember / catch the podcasts.

Pretty sure that could be automated away if there was enough interest in seeing it so ... maybe? It would really depend on how it might help us with our current reach.

Comment: I know if there's anyone like me out there, I like the fact that I can download the podcast via spotify and listen to it in "offline mode" so I don't use any of my cellular data.

Comment: I second this. For those of us that don't use apple devices it's rather inconvenient to not be able to download them and listen on the move. I was actually just about to ask this question myself.

Comment: I [third](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/341905/37429) this. As @SaggingRufus comments, downloading stuff when on wifi is very useful to listen while on public transport :)

Comment: But you can download from soundcloud.com/stack-exchange, click on "...".

Comment: @philipxy you still can't beat the convenience of just following SO on Spotify and having it automatically download the podcast next time you are in wifi range

Comment: I would love them on Spotify personally. Never used SoundCloud and don't plan to any time soon.

Comment: @JamesHughes What does an Apple device have to do with this?

Comment: @TylerH everything... https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-overflow-podcast/id1033688462?mt=2 if it's on ITunes, why isn't it on Spotify (especially given Google Play Podcasts aren't yet rolled out globally).

Comment: To get Soundcloud offline (automatically via the app) you have to pay, and I already pay for Spotify, so +1 for this from me

Comment: @JamesHughes I'm pretty sure you can get the iTunes podcasts via Apple's Music app for Android.

Comment: @JamesHughes iTunes can be used on non-Apple devices just fine. I have had it on my Android phone before and I have it on my Windows PC. Though to be fair I wasn't aware they uploaded their podcast to iTunes.

Comment: Another +1 from me as well, as I would like to get it on Spotify (it happens to be the streaming service I went for as well...)

Comment: So.. do we need to ask another question as Feature Request for podcasts to be on Spotify or just turn this one into a FR?

Comment: @Lafexlos couldn't I just edit the question to include the feature request tag?

Comment: Another vote here for Spotify, and I'd like to add something. There's a lot of talk floating around about SoundCloud being in dire straits financially. Its future is looking rather uncertain.

Comment: There are plenty of podcast apps that let you download episodes of the Stack Overflow podcast offline. One example, Player.fm, here's Stack Overflow in their directory: http://player.fm/series/the-stack-overflow-podcast-1123725 Here's the feed URL for other podcast apps: http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:4273388/sounds.rss

Comment: @SaggingRufus I did not know about the auto-download feature on Spotify. That's awesome!

Comment: Any decent podcast app will let you download them.

Comment: It would be nice if the podcast was available on a platform that wasn't blocked by the Chinese firewall too. It's inconvenient having to connect through a VPN.

Answer (score 5):

Podcast integration into Spotify is only done through [LibSyn](https://blog.libsyn.com/2016/01/12/how-to-get-your-podcast-into-spotify/), which is a service the podcast team are not currently using. It would be possible to replicate or move the podcast to LibSyn at a cost, so this was discussed in September; it was seen as a low priority at that time.

*However*, Spotify is **not** required for the podcast to be "...download[ed] when they come out and listen[ed] to [..] whenever...", you can subscribe to the show in a wide variety podcast apps to do this. Use the podcast's subscription URL: http://stackoverflow.blog/feed/podcast/

The podcast is also available via [Google Play](https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/Ii3bqwtykzjv5hvovej65fv5e2q?t%3DThe_Stack_Overflow_Podcast%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16).

Note: There are no known 'kickbacks' to having a podcast on Spotify despite it being a paid service.

Comment: How is podcast different from a song? Artists get paid from Spotify on a per listen basis (similar to how an artist get paid for a radio airing of their song). I can't imagine there is a difference between that and a podcast.

Comment: @SaggingRufus You might not imagine it, but that doesn't make it the case. You'd have to ask Spotify and Libsyn why this doesn't appear to occur (it *might*, but if it does they don't talk about it).