# What happened to the Stack Overflow podcasts?

Tags: discussion, podcast

It's two months since the last episode of Stack Overflow podcasts "aired". Is there any information somewhere on whether the project finished, paused or couldn't find a new sponsor or the second listener like me?

I miss wasting another hour with Stack Overflow HQ in NYC.

Comment: I believe we can expect https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362962/has-jon-skeet-answered-the-questions-asked-in-thanks-a-million-jon-skeet some time soon...

Comment: I can confirm that I was involved in a podcast recording on Thursday afternoon, and it was huge amounts of fun :)

Comment: @Jon now just to get you in a "roast battle" with Chuck Norris to end the debate once and for all :p

Comment: Jon pinging another Jon. Time to [change my name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562) to Jon. :p

Comment: @BhargavRao an excellent choice :p

Comment: I guess the next one will air no later than 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @BhargavRao [Could be worse](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5813/who-did-i-just-ping)

Comment: Can I just request that these get syndicated onto the likes of Spotify? Makes it easier to subscribe and listen

Comment: @JamesHughes I agree. This should be a question on its own.

Comment: @the4kman Gimme 5

Comment: @the4kman Someone beat us to the punch https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348661/stack-overflow-podcasts-on-spotify

Comment: Or [on podcast *.NET](https://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?ShowNum=1521)* *[Rocks](https://traffic.libsyn.com/dotnetrocks/dotnetrocks_1521_talking_csharp_with_bill_wagner_and_jon_skeet.mp3)*?